# DataGridVIew populated with anonymous type, how to filter?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datasource, anonymous-types

I've populated a DataGridView with a LINQ query which returns an anonymous type.

***Question**: any chance to filter the DataGridView whose data source is actually anonymous?*

```
// Setting the datagridview data source
rawDocumentsDataGridView.DataSource = rawTopics
    .SelectMany(t => t.Documents)
        .Select(d => new
            {
               DocumentId = d.Id,
               Rilevante = d.IsRelevant,
               TopicId = d.Topic.Id // foreign key
            }).ToList();

// Make it not visibile, waiting for master change
rawDocumentsDataGridView.Visible = false;

// When master selection changed...
void rawTopicsDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (rawTopicsDataGridView.CurrentRow == null) return;

    // Get selected topic id
    int tid = (int) rawTopicsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["TopicId"].Value;

    // Filter rawDocumentsDataGridView based on topic id
    // WARNING: PSEUDO CODE
    var oldDataSource = (List<AnonymousType>)rawDocumentsDataGridView.DataSource;
    rawDocumentsDataGridView.DataSource = oldDataSource
       .Where(d => d.TopicId == tid);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you keep doing that (paraphrasing) "DataSource = DataSource.Where(...)" you are going to be filtering *inside* the filtered data repeatedly; but in this case I would:

a: store the list in a field for re-use, *and*

b: not us an anonymous type

```
class DocumentRow {
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public bool Rilevante {get;set;}
    public int TopicId {get;set;}
}
...
List<DocumentRow> allData;
...
allData = rawTopics.SelectMany(t => t.Documents)
    .Select(d => new DocumentRow
        {
           DocumentId = d.Id,
           Rilevante = d.IsRelevant,
           TopicId = d.Topic.Id // foreign key
        }).ToList();
...
rawDocumentsDataGridView.DataSource = allData
   .Where(d => d.TopicId == tid).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes I was wrong, I was going to filter already filtered data. That's right. But I'd like to know how to do it with anonymous types anyway...

Comment: @Gremo - there *is* a trick called cast-by-example, but it is not worth it, really. Seriously; don't use an anonymous type here. They only make sense when the data is produced and consumed in the same context (or is *only* used by things like reflection). This isn't the case here. You could also do the filtering via reflection, but that is slow *and* brittle.

Comment: Fine, I will expose the field. I agree with you about reflection... it's not worth...

Comment: @Gremo - the field doesn't have to be public (if by *expose* you mean public)